# Stop calendar <td> from auto-resizing despite the width and height being fixed

Tags: html, css

I would like to ensure the width and height of my table don't automatically resize when the browser is re-sized whether there's is content in the cells or not.

I've fixed the widths and heights of the cells both in full width mode and in the media queries but at the moment the `<td>` with the ids #prevmonthdates, #nextmonthdates, #currentmonthdates seem to be re-sizing specifically between the widths 768 and 1024

```css
.maindiv {
 width: 1280px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/* LHS div */
.div_lhs_menu {
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 float: left;
}

/* Main menu */
.js-css-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

.js-css-menu, .js-css-menu ul, .js-css-menu li {
  list-style: none; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
}

.js-css-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.js-css-menu > li {
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background-color: #D6D6D6;
}

.js-css-menu > li > a {
  color: #000000; 
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.js-css-menu > li:hover > a {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  color: #3366FF;
}

/* Dropdown */
.js-css-menu > li div {
  position: absolute; 
  display: none;
  background: #D6D6D6;
}

.js-css-menu > li:hover div {
  display: block;
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul {
  float: none;
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul li {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul li:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #407D94; 
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li {
  display: block; 
  float: none; 
  position: relative;
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div {
  width: 150px; 
  top: 0;
  left: 181px; /* Adjust the left value according to the width of the vertical menu */
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div ul li:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #407D94;
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div ul li a {
  color: #555;
}

/*@media screen and (max-width : 768px), screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)  {  */
@media screen and (max-width : 768px) {

 /* Vertical */
 .js-css-menu.vertical {
   width: 100%; /* Adjust the width of the vertical menu */
 }
}

/* Generic table styling */
.overalldivcalendartable {
 margin: 20px 0 12px 20px;
 float: left;
}

.controlsdivcalendartable {
 float: left;
}

table { 
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed; 
}

th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold; 
  padding: 6px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

td { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Disable div to be used for media query calendar */
#divcalendartable {
 visibility: visible;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
}

#divcalendartabletwo {
 visibility: hidden;
 z-index: 1;
}

#divcalendartable, #divcalendartabletwo {
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#btnPrevYr, #btnPrev, #monthandyear, #btnNext, #btnNextYr {
 font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   cursor: pointer;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 20px;
   margin-right: 20px;
   /*background: #00FFCC;*/      
}

#monthandyearspan {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*background: #00FFCC;*/
}   

#monthandyear {
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
}

.daysheader {
  background: #C0C0C0;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#prevmonthdates, #nextmonthdates, #currentmonthdates  {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#prevmonthdates, #nextmonthdates {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#currentmonthdates {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*Apply styling UL cellvaluelist*/
#cellvaluelist {
  font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;  
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 130px;
}

/*Apply styling on all LI items in the UL cellvaluelist*/
#cellvaluelist > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F5F5F5;
  width: 130px;
}

/*Eliminate border on last list item*/
#cellvaluelist > li:last-child {
  border: none;
  width: 130px;
}

/*Styling for the span in the main list*/
#cellvaluelist > li span {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
 
  -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
}

/*Shared styling for swim and chrono*/
.swim, .chrono {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 130px; 
}

/*Styling for the list items in the table cells*/
.swim {
  background: #626FD1;
}

/*Hover on the 1st LI item on the list in the table cell*/
.swim:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Styling for the list items in the table cells*/
.chrono {
    background: #EDCF47;
}

/*Hover on the 2nd LI item on the list in the table cell*/
.chrono:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Styling for the list items in the table cells*/
.couponcode {
    background: #47ED4D;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/*Hover on the last LI item on the list in the table cell*/
.couponcode:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Apply the hover on the UL coupontooltipullist*/
.couponcode:hover .coupontooltipullist {
    display: block;
}

/*UL in the tooltip*/
.coupontooltipullist {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 5px;
}

/*Shared UL and LI list properties in the tooltip*/
.coupontooltipullist, .coupontooltip_li_list {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

/*LI in the tooltip*/
.coupontooltip_li_list {
    background: #D6D6D6;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F5F5F5;
    padding: 10px;
 }

/*IMG in the LI in the tooltip*/
.coupontooltipimg {
    width: 55px;
    height: 48px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;    
}

/*Span in the LI in the tooltip*/
.coupontooltiplistspan {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 768px) {

 td { 
   width: 130px;
   height: 100px;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
 td { 
   width: 130px;
   height: 100px;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width : 1224px) {
 td { 
   width: 130px;
   height: 100px;
 }

}
```

```html
   <div class="maindiv">

        <div class="horizontalmenubar">

          <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">MAIN MENU</label>
          
          <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">

          <ul id="menu"> <!-- removed id="menu" -->

            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a>
              <!-- <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
              </ul>-->
            </li>
          
            <li>
              <a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a>
              <!-- <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
              </ul>-->
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a>
              <!-- <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
              </ul>-->
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

       <div class="div_lhs_menu">

        <ul class="js-css-menu responsive vertical">
          <li><a href="#overalldivcalendartable">Calendar</a>
           <!--<div>

              <ul>
                <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
              </ul>

              <ul>
                <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div> -->

          </li>
          
          <li><a href="#">Dboard option 2</a>
           <!--<div>

              <ul>
                <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
              </ul>

              <ul>
                <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div> -->
          </li>

          <li><a href="#">Dboard option 3</a>
           <!--<div>

              <ul>
                <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
              </ul>

              <ul>
                <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div> -->
          </li>
        </ul>     
        </div>

       <!-- JS targets this div -->
      <div class="overalldivcalendartable">

           <!-- <div id="year"></div> -->

           <div class="controlsdivcalendartable">
               <span id="btnPrevYr" title="Previous Year"><span><<</span></span>

               <span id="btnPrev" title="Previous Month"><span><</span></span>

               <!-- <input type="button" src="images/btnprevmonth.png" alt="Submit" id="btnPrev"/>-->

               <!-- <div id="month"></div> -->

              <!-- JS targets this div -->
              <div id="monthandyear"></div>

               <!--<input type="button" src="images/btnnextmonth.png" alt="Submit" id="btnNext"/>-->

               <span id="btnNext" title="Next Month"><span>></span></span>
                
               <span id="btnNextYr" title="Next Year"><span>>></span></span>      
          </div>

           <div class="clear"></div>

           <div id="divcalendartable"></div>

            <div id="divcalendartabletwo"></div>         
      </div>
   </div>
```

Code [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1266/)

When testing please dont forget the full screen [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1266/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) to `fixed` in the `table` part of the CSS:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

Comment: tried that but the cells still resize when the browser is resized ... see latetst fiddle .. https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1267/embedded/result/

Comment: I've also explicitly set the width and height of the table using <td> IDs but no luck

Comment: When I tested on same fiddle, it only resized the cells while the browser changed size. Once the window resize was finished, the table returns to the correct size.

Comment: I've figured out my issue ... it's regarding some code I had earlier related to the swapping between two calendar divs ... one again @Anthony ... thanks